# Compiling WIN32 code with GCC

Tags: c++, winapi, gcc

I have tried to compile some C++ WIN32 code with GCC through DevC++ (MinGW GCC). It seams that it failed to link the objects and it didn't give me a clear error message: "[PathToSource] > Error 1".

Tried the same thing with Eclipse (MinGW GCC) and it compiled. However, not all of the resources show as I have an icon set to compile as the icon of the application, it's loaded from the resource files. I also get a console window in the background as I run the application.

What is the cause of this? How can I make the resource files compile with the code and also avoid the loading of a console window in the background.

I was also wondering if there's a way to compile WIN32 code in Linux through GCC, or a way to port it for the same compiler.

Comment: The console is because executable's subsystem is set to CLI, and not to GDI. Try linker switch `--subsystem`.

Comment: In addition to ruslik comment check out: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2009-03/msg01028.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resource files in Eclipse:**

In the **Build Steps** of the project, there needs to be entered the command and the full path to the resource and its output file.

```
windres ../Resources/resource_file.rc -o ../Debug/resource_file.o
```

In the **Tool Settings** of the project in the linker options, the path to the resource output file needs to be added in order for the resources to be linked into the executable file.

```
../Debug/resource_file.o
```

**Avoid the console window:**

A linker flag needs to be specified for GUI only.

```
-mwindows
```

**In Eclipse**:

Enter the flag in the project **Tool Settings** in **Linker flags**.

Answer (score 4):

Try compiling in command prompt and see what happens.

for your resource file try this in the command prompt.

`windres resource_file.rc -o resource_file.o` and finally to build your code, `g++ resource_file.o -o app.exe app.cpp`

Comment: You didn't specify anything about the other problems but I overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried to compile some C++ WIN32
>   code with GCC through DevC++ (MinGW
>   GCC). It seams that it failed to link
>   the objects and it didn't give me a
>   clear error message: "[PathToSource] >
>   Error 1".

Have you included a path to the Windows SDK? On my computer it is at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\x64`

(Note I have Visual Studios Installed on my Computer)

Compile you program with the appropriate [gcc library setting](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC13)s.

> Tried the same thing with Eclipse
>   (MinGW GCC) and it compiled. However,
>   not all of the resources show as I
>   have an icon set to compile as the
>   icon of the application, it's loaded
>   from the resource files. I also get a
>   console window in the background as I
>   run the application.

Check the resource settings to see where Eclipse is referencing your Windows Library.

> What is the couse of this? How can I
>   make the resource files compile with
>   the code and also avoid the loading of
>   a console window in the background.

Develop your applications in Visual Studio. If you cannot afford Visual Studio and you are a hobby programm consider [Visual Studios Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

> I was also wondering if there's a way
>   to compile WIN32 code in Linux through
>   GCC, or a way to port it for the same
>   compiler.

If you mean the WINAPI, then no, not as far as I know. If you want compatibility you should stick with the standard C++ library.

There are, however, universal libraries that you might find useful:

1. http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/
2. http://stdcxx.apache.org/#platforms
3. http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html
4. [Cross Platform Lbiraries (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623455/c-common-frameworks-libraries)

Comment: Thanks for the first tip, I didn't do that.